# Is it possible for Invoke-WebRequest to transparently authenticate with the user credentials of the user running the script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I've got a script that basically creates a user account on a number of systems, including Active Directory, and an IIS webserver that authenticates against that same Active Directory Domain.

Right now, if I just do my `Invoke-WebRequest` without specifying credentials, I get a 401 error, and if I use the credential switch, I have to specify or prompt for credentials.  However, when it creates the Active Directory account, PowerShell is smart enough to uses the credentials of the user running the script to create the account, without having to specify or prompt for credentials.

Is it possible to do this same thing with `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: Can't find a good dupe for it. Posting now. Happy to help a respected SE user

Comment: @Matt Yeah, I searched around (including SO) and only found answers saying it wasn't possible, or suggesting hard-coding creds in the script.  Terrible.  But thanks a bunch, this is a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [TechNet for Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901(v=wps.630).aspx) the `-UseDefaultCredentials` switch should do exactly what you are asking for:

> Indicates that the cmdet uses the credentials of the current user to send the web request.